# Reference needed: theory of modules over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I need to get hold of any relevant literature on the structure theory of modules over the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

One result in particular which has been described as 'fairly standard structure theory of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules' is the following:

> Every $\mathbb{Z}_p$-submodule of $\mathbb{Q}_p^r$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p^m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ for some $m,n$.

Where might I find a proof of this result and similar ones? Do you know of a good textbook and/or any research papers covering this topic?

Comment: First of all I would wonder how much the result is specific for $\mathbb Z_p$ versus how much it would work for any complete DVR, or any DVR, or any PID. All of these have their modules studied to some extent (beyond the very well-known f.g. ones) I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $W_0=\Bbb{Q}_p^r$ and $V_0$ the $\Bbb{Z}_p$-submodule and $j=0$.

Take $\tilde{a}_j\in V_j-0$, let $\tilde{B}_j=\tilde{a}_j\Bbb{Q}_p\cap V_j$, then $\tilde{B}_j$ is either $\tilde{B}_j=\tilde{a}_j\Bbb{Q}_p$ or $\tilde{B}_j=\tilde{a}_j p^{-n} \Bbb{Z}_p$.

- If $\tilde{B}_j=\tilde{a}_j p^{-n} \Bbb{Z}_p$ then $\tilde{a}_j p^{-n} $ is the image of some $b_j\in V_0$. Set $B_j=b_j\Bbb{Z}_p$.
- If $\tilde{B}_j=\tilde{a}_j \Bbb{Q}_p$ then it is still true that there is some $b_j\in V_0$ such that $\tilde{B}_j$ is the image in $V_j$ of $B_j=b_j\Bbb{Q}_p$.

Let $W_{j+1} = W_j/\tilde{a}_j\Bbb{Q}_p, V_{j+1} = V_j/\tilde{B}_j$ (quotient group)

Note that $V_{j+1}$ is a $\Bbb{Z}_p$-submodule of $W_{j+1}$.

Replace $j$ by $j+1$ and repeat, until $V_d=0$.

Then $$V_0=\bigoplus_{j=0}^{d-1} B_j$$

Comment: You are describing $V_d$ as obtained by successively taking extensions with either $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (up to isomorphism). Why are all these extensions split/why do we end up with a direct sum?

Comment: Not sure of what you are asking. Each time $a_j$ is a representative in $V_0$. It is clear that $\bigoplus_{j=0}^{d-1} B_j\to V_0$ surjects, and it injects because the $a_j$ are $\Bbb{Q}_p$-linearly independent. @Thorgott

Comment: The argument as you've written it right now seems to conflate $a_j$ and its image in $V_j$ when writing $a_j\mathbb{Q}_p\cap V_j$. It seems to me that the argument needs something like surjectivity of $a_j\mathbb{Q}_p\cap V_0\rightarrow\overline{a_j}\mathbb{Q}_p\cap V_j$ (where the bar denotes image in the quotient) to work, but it's not clear to me why that would be the case.

Comment: Ok, then what is the map $(a_j+C_j)\mathbb{Q}_p\cap V_j\rightarrow V_0$? Clearly, it should map $a_j+C_j\mapsto a_j$, but what guarantees that this extends to a well-defined map? A priori, it seems to me as if there might be more allowable denominators in $V_j$ than there are in $V_0$.

Comment: @Thorgott I edited the answer according to your pedantic requirement.